What's a good way to explain special relativity to a layman?
For quantum mechanics, the electron double slit experiment is a good starting point.  Lay people have heard of electrons in high school, and think of them as particles.  They're familiar with water waves, and with a quick YouTube video you can show them interference patterns of water waves.  So with electrons, it really gets across the point that something seems to go through both holes and interferes with itself.
What's something equivalent for special relativity?  Start with someone throwing a baseball on a train, where both the baseball and the train are traveling at 1/2 (or 3/4) of the speed of light, then tell them the speed of the ball w.r.t. the ground?  Then you can get into "but speed is just time over distance," which shows that either time or distance must be different for the two observers.
Or is there some better way?

I think without an experiment like Michelson you can not start. At least you ave to say that there exist experiments which show, that c is independent on the movement of the senderm whle this is not true for baseballs or sound.

You can run through the one-dimensional train-station thought experiment with normal train and station velocities and no math harder than introductory algebra.

Questions with opinion-based answers are off-topic here.

If they are great with graph plotting arguments, then Minkowski diagrams are the obvious way.

I would start from a Keating_experiment which compared synchronized atomic clock readings on airbus after the flight to the ones stationary in Earth based laboratory. They disagreed on time lapse rate, and hence SR time dilation direct proof which layman would be amazed to hear of. Then you can introduce particle mass increase in particle accelerators and so on.

First of all, you have to start with $c$ being constant in all reference frames. If this is not already understood, then you have to start with a discussion of the Michelson-Morley experiment and learn to feel comfortable with this fact.
From there, I think a simple discussion of time and clocks is warranted: a clock is something that counts oscillations. First we had the oscillations of the sun and moon in the sky (defining days and months). Now we have quartz crystal oscillators in our wrist watches and phones. Atomic clocks are "the best" clocks because they oscillate the fastest, yielding a lot of precision.
The easiest clock to analyze the effects of special relativity on is one which "counts" bounces of light between two mirrors (I like to picture them oriented so the light bounces up and down). You can then determine the time per clock cycle by the distance $d$ between the two mirrors
$$t_\text{cycle}=\frac{2d}{c}$$
Then you can consider moving into a reference frame (with relative velocity $v$ compared to the rest frame) where the clock moves perpendicular to the light bounces (let's say the clock moves to the right in this frame). Now, as the light bounces up and down, it also moves to the right, so a full clock cycle requires the light to travel a longer path, so the clock cycle time is "slower" in this frame. Some algebra and some geometry can be worked out to determine the factor to which the clock is slower in this frame.
